# why if I put a filter on an output I modify the source signal? is this a simulink bug?

Tags: matlab, debugging, signals, simulink

I know it sounds strange and that's a bad way to write a question,but let me show you this odd behavior.

[image]

as you can see this signal, r5, is nice and clean. exactly what I expected from my simulation.

now look at this:
[image]

this is EXACTLY the same simulation,the only difference is that the filter is now not connected. I tried for hours to find a reason,but it seems like a bug.
This is my file, you can test it yourself disconnecting the filter.

----edited.

Tried it with simulink 2014 and on friend's 2013,on two different computers...if Someone can test it on 2015 it would be great.

(attaching the filter to any other r,r1-r4 included ''fixes'' the noise (on ALL r1-r8),I tried putting it on other signals but the noise won't go away).

the expected result is exactly the smooth one, this file showed to be quite robust on other simulations (so I guess the math inside the blocks is good) and this case happens only with one of the two''link number'' (one input on the top left) set to 4,even if a small noise appears with one ''link number'' set to 3.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Interesting. It seems to me that the only thing the filter could affect is the time step used in the integration, assuming you are using a dynamic time step (which is the default). So, my guess is that (if this is not a bug) your system is numerically unstable/chaotic. Have you tried different solvers, different precision and limited or fixed time steps?

Comment: I'm using the default time step, the system may very well be chaotic since its huge nonlinearity: it's a robot with no friction and 4 planar arms ''hit'' by external forces...with different solver what do you mean? I'll try with a fixed time step in a moment

Comment: The type of ode-solver. If it's set to ode45, try ode23, which should already be less susceptible to noise. Or try another. You can find the solver settings under Simulation > Configuration Parameters...

Comment: this is ode23, I guess you do have a point...http://imgur.com/aMhTWTZ I will try the other ones, it seems like the problem is here. ''basically'' what happens? those solver amplify some numerical noise since they use a too small time step?

Comment: I solved the problem using a fixed time step of 0.001, thank you a lot,this is the first time I get an answer in less than 30 minutes :) if you want feel free to answer the question (if you can explaining me why is there such a big difference between solvers behaviour) to get your deserved reputation.

Comment: Something like that. It can occur when differentiating signals (for instance in a PID block or du/dt derivative block). If you differentiate noise, it will blow up. If you differentiate noise with a smaller time step, it will most likely blow up even more. To overcome the problem, try using a fixed time step, change your precision, or better: avoid differentiation, use some type of state estimator to obtain derivatives or calculate analytically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the only thing the filter could affect is the time step used in the integration, assuming you are using a dynamic time step (which is the default). So, my guess is that (if this is not a bug) your system is numerically unstable/chaotic. It could also be related to noise, caused by differentiation. Differentiating noise over a smaller time step mostly makes things even worse.

Solvers such as ode23 and ode45 use a dynamic time step. ode23 compares a second and third order integration and selects the third one if the difference between the two is not too big. If the difference is too big, it does another calculation with a smaller timestep. ode45 does the same with a fourth and fifth order calculation, more accurate, but more sensitive. Instabilities can occur if a smaller time step makes things worse, which could occur if you differentiate noise.

To overcome the problem, try using a fixed time step, change your precision/solver, or better: avoid differentiation, use some type of state estimator to obtain derivatives or calculate analytically.